# bulk edit chrome history items

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I visit a website frequently and it's domain has changed (from `foo.com` to `foo-bar.com`). My history is full of the old-domain entries, which is very annoying, because I get a lot of 404s. I wonder if it's possible to **bulk** edit urls in Google Chrome history?

Comment: Aside from what sounds like a botched website deployment (any web dev worth their salt would have put redirects in place to prevent the 404s), do you want to edit the URLs or just remove the old URLs?

Comment: It's intentional, that the domain has changed, and it does not redirect. I'd better keep the urls. - Removing them is not that hard with some hotkey afaik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome stores it's local history in an SQLite file called `History`.

On Windows you can find this file [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6ndeqflOq0M):

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERHERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

The OSX location of this file is (as per @fodma1's comment):

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/
```

I grabbed the free SQLite browser from [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and opened the history file. In there is a table called `urls`, opening this lists all the historic URLs.

You can then edit each line manually one by one or run a small SQL script to change multiple entries.

[image: SQLite Browser]

This SQL script will work for you:

```sql
UPDATE urls
SET url = REPLACE(url,".foo.",".foo-bar.")
WHERE url LIKE "%foo%";
```

Comment: Thank you, it's under `sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History` on OS X

Comment: The location appears to have changed for me on OSX. This may be a better reference for the location: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8936878/245915.