# Delete translate.google.com from Chrome History

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever you type a new word into Google Translate, it changes the URL and saves it into your history. Sure, fine, whatever, but I am trying to go through my Google History and now it's completely polluted with pages and pages of Google Translate urls. How can I clear this out of my history so going through my history is actually usable?

Things I've tried:
Using `Better History` to search for translate.google.com and then delete them this way. This crashes my browser.

Using normal Chrome history, searching translate.google.com, selecting all with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and then deleting. This does 150 at a time and essentially freezes up my browser each time. I would never actually get through my history this way I can't even get close to clearing a day using this method.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of two ways:

1. Open this page in Incognito mode
2. Open this webpage with an additional browser.
   Looking forward to more answers
   It's so annoying, especially when I need to look for something from the browser history

**Update**: Use the [History Blocker by Site](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-blocker-by-site/keamekimefemnbgegbfkdkmbomaahfai)
 free Chrome extension to block the logging of specific websites.

Comment: "Annoying" ain't a strong enough word for that. Looking for a site I found 2 days ago and forgot to bookmark was a real pain before. Google "pollutes" it own history browser feature. It is so stupid it needs a third party extention to fix it. Thanks for the recent edit which solved my issue in seconds. +1

Answer (score 1):

You may try this [History Blacklist](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/history-blacklist/dglhdhjfhaikplcgklplalmejcahjheo) extension.

Open its option page, type `translate.google.com` and it will work.

About **Better History**, when you search `translate.google.com` and click **Delete**, you just need to be patient and wait (in my case, about 10 minutes) and then all `translate.google.com` will be removed.

Comment: It looks abandoned.  Does it still work?  Someone claims it doesn't: https://github.com/smrq/chrome-history-blacklist/issues/6

Comment: Hi @oskar, in my case, I am using it in Chromium Version 113.0.5672.93 (Official Build) (64-bit), I've been using it for 3 months and it works 99% of the time

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I clear this out of my history

> **Delete history**
>
> - On your computer, go to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/).
> - At the bottom, click "History".
> - At the top-right, click "Clear history".
> - Click "OK".

Source: [See and delete your translation history - Computer - Google Translate Help](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142479?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

If you want to directly edit the Chrome History file see [macos - bulk edit chrome history items - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1047610/bulk-edit-chrome-history-items)

Comment: Well I don't want to delete the entire history, if you read my post, I mean obviously I know how to do that, but I guess editing the sql database directly is my only hope, thanks.

Comment: The first bit of my answer is addressing only the translate history not the whole history. I don't have Chrome to test so I don't know if that only clears the online translate history or removes it from the local chrome history as well. That may depend on whether you are logged into chrome and how you have sync configured.

Comment: What you described only deletes the history of the Google Translate web app, it does not clear it from Google Chrome History.